# A semicircle has a radius of 2 m. Determine the dimensions of a rectangle with the greatest area that is inscribed in it.

Tags: optimization

$y^2 + x^2 = 4$

$A(x) = 2xy$  (make base of semicircle = $2x$)

plug it in:
$A(x) = (\space 2\sqrt{(4-y^2)}\space)\cdot y$

Final derivative:
$$\begin{align}
A'(x) & = \frac{-2y^2}{\sqrt{4-y^2} + 2\sqrt{(4-y)}} \\
& \\
& \\
0 & = \frac{-2y^2}{\sqrt{4-y^2} + 2\sqrt{(4-y)}} \\
\end{align}$$
$y = \frac{2\sqrt 2}{3} $

but the answer is 1.42 x 0.71

how do you get this? did i make a mistake?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86793/find-the-area-of-the-largest-rectangle-that-can-fit-inside-a-semi-circle-of-radi

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116955/maximizing-area-of-a-rectangle-inscribed-in-a-semicircle

Comment: @labbhattacharjee i approached the question differently..

Answer (score 1):

For starters, $A(x,y)= 2xy$ where $2x$ is the base of the **rectangle**, not the semicircle.  Also, if $x=\sqrt{4-y^2}$, you mean to say that $A(y) = 2y\sqrt{4-y^2}$.

Now, your derivative isn't correct.  You should have gotten

$$A^{\prime}(y) = 2\sqrt{4-y^2} - \frac{2y^2}{\sqrt{4-y^2}} = \frac{8-4y^2}{\sqrt{4-y^2}}.$$

The maximizing value then is $y=\sqrt{2}$ and thus $x=\sqrt{2}$.  So the dimensions of the rectangle are $2\sqrt{2}\times \sqrt{2}$.